# AWS IAM: Using restricted policy while assuming role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an application with multiple components that interacts with customer's AWS resources. Customer passes an application wide AWS role which contains all the necessary permissions for all the components and these components assumes the role to do the necessary interactions. Issue with this approach is that a particular component gets unnecessary permissions which are not needed and were defined for other components.

What I want to do is that a particular component should have only those permissions which are needed by it. I know before hand that what permissions are required for a particular component. One approach that I can think of is that my main application assumes the role and passes the optional policy document to further restrict the permissions for a particular component and then pass the assumed role AWS credentials to that component.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html

Downside of this approach is that assumed role credentials have to be sent over the wire from main application to that component which seems insecure.

Is there any other approach which does not need passing credentials over wire? Main application has application wide roleArn and knows about permissions needed for each component.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify your concerns? You seem to be worried about *credentials being sent over the wire* -- however, when your application makes the AssumeRole API call, what you have is exactly credentials being sent over the wire from STS to the caller! Why is this acceptable while passing credentials between your application components is not? Have you precisely defined your threat model?